# How to sent an installation error report that occurred while not having an internet connection?

Tags: lubuntu, error-handling, 13.10

I wanted to contribute to Lubuntu by testing their daily dev build. I tried installing it but got an error. Not a problem, that's the point of testing! ;) But since the error comes before having a Wi-Fi connection, it can't sent the report. However, it then goes back to live mode and from there I can connect to Wi-Fi.

Now how can I have it send the error report?

Or get the logs so I can manually file the bug on Launchpad?

Comment: Hi, please take a look here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/Testing

Comment: @vasa1 I can't find it there

Comment: That link is an introduction for people who are interested in testing and contributing to the process in the manner the wiki describes. It was _not_ meant as an answer your question. I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at [How to report an Installer bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/Overview/Install_Bugs). Quoting from there:

> When installing a new iso, you can hit a bug during the actual
>   install. This table is to give guidance on what best to report such a
>   bug at.

...

> If you are unsure of the application, or for further information,
>   please have a read of [Finding the Right Package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage).  Sometimes the machine
>   with the bug has no internet access, in this case:
>
> ubuntu-bug is a wrapper around apport-cli and apport-cli has an option
>   for saving the report for later. The documentation says:
>
> --save=PATH In bug filing mode, save the collected information into a file instead of reporting it. This file can then be reported later on
>   from a different machine.
>
> Saving the bug report to a file can be useful when the machine you are
>   testing on does not have internet access. After saving the file and
>   moving it to a system with internet access you can use 'apport-cli
>   my.crash' (where my.crash is the saved crash file) to send the report
>   to Launchpad.

It's my understanding that the QA Team would really like people to test in the manner they suggest (in addition to whatever else one does). So, if you're willing, I'm sure they'd be too happy to have you join them!

BTW, here's where I put up your issue: [Facebook permalink to Lubuntu Official](https://www.facebook.com/groups/lubuntu.official/permalink/541667909223367/) if you aren't allergic to Facebook ;)